# Partial value constraint of sql server table

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a SQL Server table with two columns id:INT and flagged:BOOLEAN. Is it possible to add a constraint that ensures that there is only one entry for (id=a, flagged=b) where b = 1?

For example:

ok

`(id=1, flagged=1) 
(id=1, flagged=0) 
(id=1, flagged=0)`

not ok

`(id=1, flagged=1) 
(id=1, flagged=1)
(id=1, flagged=0)`

Comment: If you search on here (or the web at large) for `conditional unique constraint` you should find plenty of results. Usually, either a filtered index or indexed view (for earlier versions) fits the bill.

Comment: @Lloyd Unique Filtered Index works exactly in this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Unique Index with filter:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON your_table(id)
   WHERE flagged=1;
```

Demo:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e897c/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(id INT, flagged INT);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON your_table(id)
   WHERE flagged=1;


INSERT INTO your_table(id, flagged)
VALUES (1, 0), (1,1), (1,0);

INSERT INTO your_table(id, flagged)   -- will fail
VALUES (1,1);

/* Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.your_table'
   with unique index 'idx_name'. The duplicate key value is (1).*/
```

Comment: For downvoters leave comment with message what is not working

Comment: Perfect answer. Not sure why anyone would have wanted to down-vote this. Thanks lad2025.