# unique index is not enforced if IsActive column is false

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have an accountBranchMap table which has three columns:

AccountId, BranchId, IsActive.

There is an unique index on AccountId to ensure that each account can only map to one branch.

Is there a way the unique index will only be checked on the records with IsActive = 1 ? 
e.g If there a row of (AccountId = 1, BranchId = 1, IsActive = 0 ), I can still insert (1, 2, 1) into the table. There can exist multiple duplicated AccountId as long as its IsActive value is false.

I am using SQL-Server 2008R2 SP1

Thank you.

Comment: Filtered index. See the second answer in the dupe.

Comment: @Sean See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473877/partial-value-constraint-of-sql-server-table/32473929#32473929